# How to Filter and collect on Uni Quarkus Panache Reactive

Tags: quarkus, quarkus-panache

I am trying to convert a Quarkus Panache where I can stream and collect from List

```
(query.stream().collect(Collectors.mapping(Employee::getCountry, Collectors.toList())))
.stream().filter(Objects::nonNull).distinct().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()));
```

to Quarkus Panache Reactive I am not sure how to filter and collect For Example

```
Class Filter {
    public List<String> countries;
    public List<String> states;
    public List<String> locations;
}
Class Employee extends PanacheEntity {
   public name ;
   public location ;
   public state;
   public country ;

   public static Uni<Filter> getComboData(){
           Filter filter = new Filter()
           PanacheQuery<Employee > query = findAll();

           //Not sure how to filter and return below type 
           // Old way 
           filter.countries =(query.stream().collect(Collectors.mapping(Employee::getCountry, 
            Collectors.toList()))).stream().filter(
             Objects::nonNull).distinct().sorted().collect(Collectors.toList()));
            //New way as it returns a Uni<List<Employee >>
             filter.countries =
 
           return Uni<Filter>
   }
}
```

Thanks!

Comment: any chance can you put an example in github ?

Comment: It was resolved by issue https://github.com/quarkusio/quarkus/issues/23739